# Как в objective-c передать массив NSString в метод?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

В objective-c мне необходимо передать в метод двумерный массив NSString. Я его объявляю `NSString *products[10][10];`, потом присваиваю какие-то значения, и не могу написать метод, чтобы он принимал его.
Компилятор не пропускает такие объявления:

```
-(void) Array : (NSString *) array[][];
-(void) Array : (NSSting[][] *) array;
```

А так же охота, чтобы метод возвращал двумерный массив NSString. Т.е. такое тоже не проходит:

```
-(NSString[][] *) ArrayCount : (int) count;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста! Как правильно писать такие методы, которые бы принимали и возвращали двумерный массив NSString? Или такое вообще не возможно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Традиционно в ObjC нет двумерных массивов — вместо них используется такое понятие как "массив массивов". То есть массив, каждым элементом которого является другой массив.

Объявить его можно либо:

```
NSArray *row1 = @[@"string1", @"string2"];
NSArray *row2 = @[@"string3", @"string4"];
NSArray *container = @[row1, row2];
```

либо:

```
NSArray *container = @[@[@"string1", @"string2"],
                       @[@"string3", @"string4"]];
```

и далее вы передаёте в метод массив `container`.

Чтобы получить элемент из массива:

```
container[0][0];
```

Так же надо добавить, что поскольку ObjC основан на C, любой C-код будет работать, включая 2D массивы, но тогда и те методы, куда эти массивы передаются надо писать на C.

Comment: Хм, спасибо. Буду работать так.